# Trying to make a formula that recognizes if another is blank and then adds a number [Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to Excel. My only programming knowledge comes from a C course in college.

I'm trying to create a sheet that will check if a group of cells are blank. When one of them is, then nothing happens, and when one of them has content then the cell with the formula will add 1400 to itself. For example, if it checks 10 cells, and 3 of them have content inside, the main cell will showcase 4200.

Here's an image of the sheet. The formula goes at the bottom and makes a sum with each column

[image: Here's an image of the sheet. The formula goes at the bottom and makes a sum with each column]

In my head, the formula would be something like `=if(isblank(B2:B17;" ";+1400))`.

What would be the correct formula?

Comment: Investigate [`COUNTA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7DC98875-D5C1-46F1-9A82-53F3219E2509) then multiply its result by 1400

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thank you! That worked perfectly, I cant believe it didn't come up in my google search.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for empty cells, count the number of non-empty cells with `COUNTA` then multiply the result by 1400:

```
=COUNTA(B2:B17)*1400
```